# Cannot convert image into .png format in Codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am uploading image to server. In whatever format i upload the image it should be converted to .png format but in my case it is giving following error and i am working on codeigniter. In core php it is working properly.

> ```
> Message: Division by zero
> Filename: controllers/Upload_user_image.php
> ```
>
> Message: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]:
>   Invalid image dimensions
>
> Message: imagesavealpha() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given
>
> Message: imagecolorallocatealpha() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given
>
> Message: imagefill() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>
> ```
> Message: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
> > Message: Undefined variable: c_image
> ```
>
> Message: imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Controller:

```
function do_upload()
{
        $cimg = $_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name'];
        $extension = pathinfo($cimg, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $srcFile_c = $_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name'];
        /*function imageToPng($srcFile, $maxSize = 100) {*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        list($width_orig, $height_orig, $type) = getimagesize($srcFile_c);
        $maxSize = 100;
        // Get the aspect ratio
        $ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig;

        $width = $maxSize;
        $height = $maxSize;                                                               

        // resize to height (orig is portrait)
        if ($ratio_orig < 1)
        {

            $width = $height * $ratio_orig;

        }
        // resize to width (orig is landscape)
        else
        {
            $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
        }

        // Temporarily increase the memory limit to allow for larger images
        ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');


       $u_name='pawan';
        switch (@$type)
        {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF: 
        $c_image = imagecreatefromgif($srcFile_c); 
        break;   
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:  
        $c_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcFile_c); 
        break;   
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $c_image = imagecreatefrompng($srcFile_c);
        break;   
        default:
        throw new Exception('Unrecognized image type ' . @$type);
        }    

        // create a new blank image
        $new_c_Image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagesavealpha($new_c_Image, true);
        $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_c_Image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($new_c_Image, 0, 0, $trans_colour);
        imagecopyresampled($new_c_Image, $c_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig,$height_orig);
         $getpng = imagepng($new_c_Image, './uploads/' . "img_" . $u_name . '.png');
}
```

This is my form:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Upload_user_image/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" />

<input type="text" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the errors to see where it is going wrong?  The one regarding `imagesavealpha` looks fairly obvious for a start as you are passing `true` instead of the resource it is expecting...

Comment: I have checked it is working fine in core php but when i had implemented my code in codeigniter it is not working. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

First upload the any format to some dummy folder and then try changing the format of the file to `png`.

```
if ($imageFileType == "jpg") {
   $jpg = "path to dummy jpg image folder";
   imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($jpg)), "path where you want to store png images");
    unlink($jpg);
} else if ($imageFileType == "jpeg") {
    $jpg = "path to dummy jpeg image folder";
    imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($jpg)),"path where you want to store png images");
    unlink($jpg);
}
```

**NOTE:** you can combine both types, but make sure you give correct extention.

Comment: Niranjan N Raju- Thanks for your answer but i have to convert it only while uploading, my above code works fine in core php but it is giving following errors in codeigniter.

Comment: you dont have to do that much of work if you follow this method. And in your code, your are converting even `png` to `png`. i think you should remove that.

Comment: in which line  you r getting this error, `Division by zero`??

Comment: This is the line $ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig; i think that image is not passed from form to the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94184/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-user3653474).